# How do I perform a multi-state decomposition with interaction effects?

Tags: interaction, factor-analysis, econometrics, exploratory-data-analysis, state-space-models

I am trying to perform a decomposition with interaction effects.  [This paper](http://ftp.iza.org/dp6730.pdf) provides a solution for n-factors where each factor has a binary state (see section 2).  I have a problem with 2 factors, one of which has binary state and the other has three states.

For example:

Factor 1 is sky condition which can be sunny or cloudy

Factor 2 is type of ice cream which can be vanilla, chocolate, or strawberry

The "start" case is vanilla on a sunny day.  The "end" case is strawberry on a cloudy day.  I can measure the money an ice cream shop makes for each combination of Factor1 and Factor2.  So for example, selling chocolate on a sunny day results in $5.50.

I'd like to perform a full decomposition with interaction effects.  What would be the formula?  Ideally the solution is expressed in terms of the example I have provided for maximum clarity.

Comment: Are these states latent? I am not sure what to make of the FA and SSM tags here.

Comment: Hi Dimitriy - I was having trouble finding relevant tags.  Perhaps those should be deleted?  I'm not sure what you mean by "latent?"  These are states that can and do exist.

Comment: I would purge those two tags.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think your example fits into the framework used in the paper.

I think what you have in mind is how revenue of the shop is determined by weather and ice cream type (btw it is odd that the shop only sells one type of icecream).

What you then need is the Regression:

$$revenue = b_0 + b_1\times cloudy + a_1\times chocolate + a_2\times strawberry + c_1\times cloudy\times chocolate + c_2\times cloudy \times strawberry$$

the interaction effects are given by $c_1$, $c_2$

Hope this helps
Martin

Comment: Hi Martin - Thank you for responding!  I am not trying to calculate nor predict revenue.  I want to measure the ceteris paribus effect of each factor on revenue.  What happens if ice cream type is changed from vanilla to chocolate with everything else held constant (i.e. its a sunny day)?  That would simply be Revenue(chocolate, sunny) - Revenue(vanilla, sunny).  I'm trying to figure out the full decomposition with interaction effects for all factors and all states.  So f00 = (vanilla, sunny) and f11 = (strawberry, cloudy)  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the regression you measure the ceteris paribus effect of cloudy (=b1), of chocolate (=a1), and of strawberry (=a2) as well as the interaction effects (=c1, c2)

I don't really see a decomposition problem in your example where a 100 percent effect is split up into different parts. I also don't really see the purpose of your analysis.

You could split up the difference between f00 and f11 into the cp effect of strawberry, the cp effect of cloudy, and the interaction of the both. But its unclear how the third possibility enters.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Martin. Please don't sign your posts. Note that your flair & a link to your userpage is automatically added to your posts. Since you're new here, you may want to read our [about page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about), which contains info for new users.